# Can't remove a DIV inside BODY which is added through a external JS function

Tags: jquery

I want to delete an DIV inside BODY when the URL contains /login. This works so far, the only thing which does not work, is that if I want to select the specific DIV, it returns nothing. It works with other DIV's in the BODY. So I think it has something to do that the DIV I want to select is still not ready in the ready function? How to solve this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/login") > -1) {
    var x = $("div[id|='trustbadge-container']")
    console.log(x) // Returns length 0.
    x.remove()
}
```

The following DIV is been addeded (inside BODY, at the end) by a external loaded JS function:

```
<div id="trustbadge-container-98e3dadd90eb493088abdc5597a70810"> </div>
```

Script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () { 
    var _tsid = 'X'; 
    _tsConfig = { 
      'yOffset': '20', /* offset from page bottom */
      'variant': 'reviews', /* default, reviews, custom, custom_reviews */
      'customElementId': '', /* required for variants custom and custom_reviews */
      'trustcardDirection': '', /* for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft */
      'customBadgeWidth': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'customBadgeHeight': '', /* for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels) */
      'disableResponsive': 'false', /* deactivate responsive behaviour */
      'disableTrustbadge': 'false' /* deactivate trustbadge */
    };
    var _ts = document.createElement('script');
    _ts.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    _ts.charset = 'utf-8'; 
    _ts.async = true; 
    _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js'; 
    var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove that element when you use their service? Are you allowed to do that if you use their service?

Comment: Andreas, Ofcourse you are allowed. It's only a test (the remove). I can't even select it. That is the problem for now.

Comment: You could try making use of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver): "The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree."

Comment: @PeterB do you have another solution why I can't find the ID? I don't want to use MutationObserver for this.

Comment: The only other alternative I see is using repeated setTimeout commands in which you check for the presence of the element, if it's not yet there then start a new cycle, and process it once found.